# Getting values between from and to date from datetimepicker

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have 2 datetimepickers in my program. One is to specify from and other is to specify to. Iam trying to get values between from and to. I passed values of 2 datetimepicker to between query but iam getting only values between a months date. if i select from date of a month and select to from another date is wont display datas.

```
SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name from Billing WHERE Bill_Date Between @From AND @To", con);
da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", dateTimePicker_FromSaleReport.Text);
da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", dateTimePicker_ToSaleReport.Text);
dataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dgv_FromToSaleReport.DataSource = dt3;
```

Comment: try to pass the date as DateTime Object instead for `Text`

Comment: can you help explaining that.

Comment: as un-lucky said, you can do like this: `dateTimePicker_FromSaleReport.Value.ToString()`. Take a look at [DateTimePicker.Value Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the DateTime object instead for Text, so first of all you have to get DateTime value from the DatePicker, and then proceed with that:

```
DateTime fromDate, toDate;

DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_FromSaleReport.Text, out fromDate);
DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_ToSaleReport.Text, out toDate);

// use DateTime.TryparseExtract if you know the format of input date

SqlDataAdapter filterAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name from Billing WHERE Bill_Date Between @From AND @To", con);
filterAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@From",SqlDbType.DateTime).value = fromDate;
filterAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@To", SqlDbType.DateTime).value = toDate;

DataTable filteredTable = new DataTable();
filterAdapter.Fill(filteredTable);
dgv_FromToSaleReport.DataSource = filteredTable ;
```

Note : please be sure about the type of column in the database, It should be DateTime in order to performs the comparison.

Comment: Still I am only able to get values between dates within a month. I have that bill_Date column in database which saves Bill date from datetipickers text.

Comment: Please cross check the type of that column in the database

Comment: varchar.. I think i shoud save date from datetime picker to database as a date object rather than datetimepicker text?

Comment: yes you have to fix that first, also needed to change the column type to DateTime

Comment: Will do that. ok thanx.:)

Comment: That worked! Iam a beginner in winforms. thanx  @unlucky.

Comment: I have a small doubt. As iam saving it as a datetime object, how can i change the format something like 1-dec-2016 rather than 1-12-2016.

Comment: You can format them before displaying, use something like `fromDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` read more about formatting [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

Comment: I am only displaying the result.